# Possible to find out if # in URL with python app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, webapp2

Is there a way to find out if the current URL for the webhandler contains a # ?
I can't get written out the URL when i use a #. 
`self.request.url` returns only the base URL when a URL with # is GET on server.

I have also tried to send the rest of the URL as an argument and print that.

```
('/(.*)', MainHandler),
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, args):
        self.response.out.write(args)
```

This will not post anything on args argument when URL is GET with a # in the URL. For everything else it successfully writes the rest of the URL after the base. Example on what kind of URL i'm trying to show: http://instahashtag.appspot.com/#/14212311

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL fragment is handled by the browser and is not passed to the server. If you need to handle it you need to write client-side code (most likely in JavaScript).